# Combining data from two SQL queries

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, webforms

I'm porting my app from Django to ASP.NET Webforms (against my will, but what can we do with the corporate world..), and I'm used to Django generating all my SQL queries so now I need help.
I have 3 tables: `proceso`,`marcador`,`marcador_progreso`

Every `proceso` has many `marcador_progreso`, which in turn is the foreign key table to `marcador`.

So basically the tables look like:

```
proceso
    id

marcador
    id
    text

marcador_progreso
    id
    marcador_id
    proceso_id
    state
```

For all the `marcador_progreso` where its `proceso_id` is the current proceso (from a QueryField in the URL), I need to list its `state` and it's respective `marcador.text`.
I've been working with EntityFramework but this is like a double query so I'm not sure how to do it.

I guess it is something that combines the following two statements, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
SELECT [state] FROM [marcador_progreso]
SELECT [text] FROM [marcador] WHERE ([id] = marcador_id)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to know about `JOIN`s to call more than one table in your `FROM` clause.  `JOIN` combines records from two or more tables in a database by using values common to each.  There are different types - the SQL example below is an `INNER` join, which gets only records where both of the tables have a match on the common value.  You may want to consider a `LEFT` join which would get any records that exist for the `LEFT` table (in this case marcador), even if there are not any matching record in the  `RIGHT`(marcador_progreso ) table.
Pop the below in Management Studio, Play with different joins.  Replace the `INNER` with `LEFT`, run it without the `WHERE`.
Read about `JOIN's.

In general, for your new venture of writing your own queries, they all start with the same basic structure:
*SELECT (UPDATE,WHATEVER DML statement, etc) (COLUMNS)* what you want to display (update,etc)
*FROM (TABLE)* where those records live 
*WHERE (FILTER/LIMIT)* conditions that must be met by the data
Happy fetching!

SQL:

```
DECLARE @ProcessoId int
SET @ProcessoId = --1

SELECT m.[STATE],mp.[TEXT] 
FROM marcador M
INNER JOIN marcador_progreso MP ON MP.marcador_id = m.id
WHERE proceso_id =  @ProcessoId
```

EF INNER example

```
var marc = from m in yourcontext.marcador
           join mp in yourcontext.marcador_progreso on m.id equals mp.marcador_id
           where proceso_id ==  processoIdvariable
```

EF LEFT example

```
  var marc = from m in yourcontext.marcador
           join mp in yourcontext.marcador_progreso on m.id equals mp.marcador_id into details
           from d in details.DefaultIfEmpty()
           where proceso_id ==  processoIdvariable
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to do a JOIN:

```
SELECT mp.state, m.text
FROM marcador_progreso as mp
INNER JOIN marcador as m
ON mp.marcador_id = m.id
```

This is an [excellent post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) that goes over the various join types.

Comment: +1, but I'd translate the two separate selects using a LEFT OUTER JOIN, but it could go either way depending on the OPs intent